# Returning a Generic Type from a Function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code. When I try to build the app I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type '[Post]' to return type '[T]'

struct Post: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let body: String
}

class Loader {
    
    func load<T: Codable>(name: String) -> [T] {
        return [Post]()
    }
    
}
```

Any ideas why?

UPDATE:

THIS WORKS:

```
class PreviewData {
    
    func load<T: Codable>(name: String) -> [T]? {
        return [Post]() as? [T]
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What about `func load(name: String) -> [Post] { return [] }`?

Answer (score 2):

You basically says my `load` method gonna return a generic array named `T` but you are trying to return Array of `Post` model , just change :

```
func load<T: Codable>(name: String) -> [T] {
    return [T]()
}
```